# How much is the estimated amount of ilmenite present on Lunar surface?

Tags: the-moon, mining, oxygen, regolith

I wanted to gauge estimated amount of ilmenite that can be extracted from Lunar regolith. From that, ultimately I want to derive the amount of oxygen that can be extracted out of it. Any estimate or references will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Ilmenite occurs in abundances as high as 25 wt% in some lunar basalts.
> Maximum yields calculated as mass of oxygen per mass of rock thus
> range from 2-2.5 wt%.

[https://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/lunar/lnews/lnmar97/oxygen.htm#:~:text=Ilmenite%20occurs%20in%20abundances%20as,from%202%2D2.5%20wt%25](https://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/lunar/lnews/lnmar97/oxygen.htm#:%7E:text=Ilmenite%20occurs%20in%20abundances%20as,from%202%2D2.5%20wt%25).

Comment: Thanks that is helpful.